# Is a SubSequence of a Char[] equal to the contents of String?

Tags: c#

Is there a quicker way to check that subsequence of a char array, from a specific index is equals that of a string?

```
bool Matches (Char[] cs, int i, string s)
{
    return cs.Skip(i).Take(s.Length).SequenceEqual(s);
}
```

Assume that `cs` and `s` are never `null`.

Quicker as in run time. 
Also can I be done without creating a new instance of a string? Since both can be seen as char arrays.

I'm hoping of something along the lines of [C's strncmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/)

Comment: `new string(cs, i, s.Length) == s;`

Comment: Define "quicker". Quicker to run? Probably don't use LINQ. Quicker to write? Maybe.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Quicker to run.

Comment: This code is fairly clear to read. Do you have any objectively measured performance issues?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel It creates 3 enumerators.  If the chararray is big it could take sometime to complete.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a simple `for` loop. This one has been designed to eliminate the bounds checks on `s`.

```
bool Matches (char[] chars, int offset, string s)
{
    if(offset < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("offset");
    if(chars.Length - offset < s.Length)
        throw new ArgumentException();
    for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        if(chars[offset + i] != s[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could always write the loop yourself and do away with the enumerators:

```
if (cs == null || s == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException();
if (i < 0 || i > cs.Length)
    throw new ArgumentException("i");
if (cs.Length - i != s.Length)
    return false;
for (int j = 0; j != s.Length; ++j) {
    if (s[j] != cs[j + i])
        return false;
}
return true;
```

But this still wouldn't be as fast as calling into a native string function, since it does bounds checking on every subscript access (normally this isn't a big deal, but since you're after speed, why not go whole-hog). So we can drop down a level of abstraction and use pointers:

```
if (cs == null || s == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException();
if (i < 0 || i > cs.Length)
    throw new ArgumentException("i");
if (cs.Length - i != s.Length)
    return false;
unsafe {
     fixed (char* ps = s, pcs_ = cs) {
        char* pcs = pcs_ + i;
        for (int j = 0; j != s.Length; ++j) {
            if (pcs[j] != ps[j])
                return false;
        }
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: I was think more along the lines of [C's strncmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/)

Comment: strncmp would tend to be slower since the strings don't have to be of equal length -- it has to keep checking until the first difference. The majority of the time, string equality checks bail out early before the loop since the strings are often simply different lengths, and therefore not equal. Always use string equality when you can.

Comment: @AdamSpeight You could invoke C's `memcmp` instead of `strncmp`.